# Selenium can't start session because url doesn't support http post

Tags: java, http, post, selenium

I'm trying to run some Selenium tests for an application while it is started, but am getting a runtime exception:

> Could not start Selenium session:  HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

The application we made has no need for a POST method. Is there any way to make Selenium work without needlessly implementing one? Why is it required in the first place?

Comment: That sounds like an error within Selenium itself, before it's interacting with your site. What exactly are you doing just before that happens?

Comment: This error happens at the line where I try to create a DefaultSelenium.  My application is running on localhost, so I use the command "new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 8080, "firefox", "/");

I haven't even done anything else yet.  I'm just trying to create the Selenium instance.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to pass for DefaultSelenium are as follows according to the api documentation:

> serverHost - the host name on which the Selenium Server resides
>
> serverPort - the port on which the Selenium Server is listening
>
> browserString - the command string used to launch the browser
>
> browserURL - the starting URL including just a domain name

You need to direct it to where an instance of your selenium server is running (which could be remotely or locally). I am going to guess that localhost:8080 is where you have deployed a separate application that you want to test with selenium.

So, the details you provide are for the selenium server, not for your application. If you download the standalone server and run it locally, you only need to change the port to match that of the selenium server instance. You can download the selenium standalone server from their main website, and when you run it, it will tell you the port that it uses (by default it is 4444).

Why not just use WebDriver instead?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("URL")
```

You can read more about how to use it on the documentation page on the selenium website.